# Spark SQL - Adding partition in hive exception

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Getting below exception while trying to run spark sql which is adding partition in hive table.

> diagnostics: User class threw exception: java.lang.LinkageError:
>   ClassCastException: attempting to
>   castjar:file:/hadoop/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/11415/spark-hdp-assembly.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.classtojar:file:/hadoop/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/11415/spark-hdp-assembly.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class

Comment: can you add your code and full error log ?